# "Related To" field on Email Message object not showing in report

Tags: emailmessage

I'm creating a report on the Email Message object. I have selected the fields I want displayed on the report, but the "Related To" field is not available to be selected. I do not see the "Related To' field anywhere. I have checked the FLS, it is set to "Read Only" and "Visible". I also checked the Field Accessibility, it is set to "Read Only", but the field is not available when I'm creating a report.

Please, I need help.

Comment: I don't think it is currently available but I will cross check with Salesforce product team to confirm. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Swetha.