# How to report on the status of email messages related to a specific record?

Tags: email, reporting, email-template, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I'd like to create a report that presents information such as the `EmailMessage.LastOpenedDate` and the `EmailMessage.Status` for emails sent that are related to a specific custom record. When I look in "Report Types" in "Setup", I don't see any way to do that; see ["Related To" field on Email Message object not showing in report](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/397138/related-to-field-on-email-message-object-not-showing-in-report) for a related but unanswered question on this.

Is adding a trigger that copies [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) fields to a custom child object that can then be included in a report the only way to work-around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `RelatedTo` is a polymorphic field on `EmailMessage` hence why it is not available on the report type

However ...

- `EmailMessage` supports custom fields
- Thus you could use a Flow or trigger to copy the relevant value(s) from the `relatedTo` Object (by first checking the key prefix of the `RelatedToId`) into `EmailMessage` custom fields
- Then, your custom report type on `EmailMessage` would have the requisite data to report on.

Comment: Thank-you cropredy - a much cleaner approach.